# How to get outgoing call number in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get outgoing call number with `intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)`, but every time I try it returns null. I did put needed permissions and action in Androidmanifest. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how to retrive number another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was wrong.

First of all intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER) gives you outgoing number while phone state is idle and turns to "null" while phone status changes to OFF_HOOK.

The easiest way was to save the number before another onRecive happens.

Comment: i am having the exact same issue, i made another if statement to check if mobile became idle when the outgoing call ends to save duration and i also tried to check for number but didnt work gives null!

Comment: in my case it was phone state as listed:
idle > ringing > offhook > idle

in first idle there was extra data with phone number