# Not getting outgoing call number

Tags: java, android

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MediaRecorder recorder;
    TelephonyManager telManager;
    boolean recordStarted;
    private Context ctx;
    static boolean status = false;
    String phoneNumber;

    public static SharedPreferences preferences;
    boolean enabled;
    private static Date date;
    public static Boolean isIncoming;
    private static String dateStr;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ctx = context;
        String action = intent.getAction();

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Numbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        enabled = preferences.getBoolean("enabled", false);

        date = new Date();

        dateStr = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();

        if (enabled) {
            if (status == false) {
                try {
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                        phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        incomingcallrecord(action, context);

                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

                        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                        incomingcallrecord(action, context);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                status = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void incomingcallrecord(String action, Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            telManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            Log.d("calling number", "calling number" + incomingNumber);
            try {
                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
                        Log.e("CALL_STATE_RINGING", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");

                        isIncoming = true;

                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

                        Log.e("incoming", "incoming call" + incomingNumber);

                        File file = createDirIfNotExists();
                        recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

                        recorder.prepare();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        recorder.start();
                        recordStarted = true;
                        status = true;
                        Log.e("Record start", " Start");

                        String insertStr = "IN_" + dateStr;

                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_2_NUMBER, insertStr);
                        Activity_Landing.dbWritable.insert(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                        Log.d("calling number ringing", "" + incomingNumber);

                        break;
                    }

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {
                        Log.e("CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");

                        isIncoming = false;

                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

                        Log.e("outgoing", "outgoing call" + incomingNumber);

                        File file = createDirIfNotExists();
                        recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

                        recorder.prepare();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        recorder.start();
                        recordStarted = true;
                        status = true;
                        Log.e("Record start", " Start");

                        String insertStr = "OUT_" + dateStr;

                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_2_NUMBER, insertStr);
                        Activity_Landing.dbWritable.insert(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                        Log.d("calling number offhook", "" + incomingNumber);

                        break;
                    }

                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {

                        Log.e("CALL_STATE_IDLE", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                        if (recordStarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recorder.reset();
                            recorder.release();
                            Log.e("Record stop", " stop");
                            recorder = null;
                            recordStarted = false;
                        }

                        Log.d("calling number idle", "" + incomingNumber);
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Log.e("Exception ------", "" + ex.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    public File createDirIfNotExists() {

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PhoneCallRecording");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "folder is created");
            }
        }
        File file;
        if (isIncoming) {
            file = new File(folder, "IN_" + dateStr + ".amr");
        } else {
            file = new File(folder, "OUT_" + dateStr + ".amr");
        }
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                if (file.createNewFile()) {
                    Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "file is created");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
}
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sadob.png)

I am developing android app from call recorder. In manifest file i am using phone state permission but cannot access outgoing call, i am getting null pointer exception.

Manifest,

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver.CallReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Post your code so that we can chck what you have done

Comment: this is my manifest file.

Comment: <receiver android:name=".Receiver.CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: @PreetikaKaur added my receiver code.Please once check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get outgoing call number in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324771/how-to-get-outgoing-call-number-in-android)

Comment: @PrakashU...Not Working.

Comment: @PreetikaKaur... finally solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

MediaRecorder recorder;
TelephonyManager telManager;
boolean recordStarted;
private Context ctx;
static boolean status = false;
String phoneNumber;

public static SharedPreferences preferences;
boolean enabled;
private static Date date;
Boolean isIncoming;
String isInOrOut;
private static String dateStr;
static long start_time, end_time;

String lastCallnumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ctx = context;
    String action = intent.getAction();

    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Numbers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    enabled = preferences.getBoolean("enabled", false);

    date = new Date();

    dateStr = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();

    if (enabled) {
        if (status == false) {
            try {
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    incomingcallrecord(action, context);
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    incomingcallrecord(action, context);
                }
            }
        } else {
            status = false;
        }
    }
}

private void incomingcallrecord(String action, Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
        telManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        Log.d("calling number", "calling number" + incomingNumber);
        try {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
                    Log.e("CALL_STATE_RINGING", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");

                    isIncoming = true;

                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

                    Log.e("incoming", "incoming call" + incomingNumber);

                    phoneNumber = incomingNumber;

                    File file = createDirIfNotExists();
                    recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    recorder.prepare();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    recorder.start();
                    recordStarted = true;
                    status = true;
                    Log.e("Record start", " Start");

                    Log.d("calling number ringing", "" + incomingNumber);

                    break;
                }

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {
                    Log.e("CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");

                    isIncoming = false;

                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

                    Log.e("outgoing", "outgoing call" + lastCallnumber);

                    File file = createDirIfNotExists();
                    recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    recorder.prepare();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    recorder.start();
                    recordStarted = true;
                    status = true;
                    Log.e("Record start", " Start");

                    Log.d("calling number offhook", "" + lastCallnumber);

                    break;
                }

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {

                    Log.e("CALL_STATE_IDLE", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
                    if (recordStarted) {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.reset();
                        recorder.release();
                        Log.e("Record stop", " stop");
                        recorder = null;
                        recordStarted = false;
                    }

                    if (isIncoming) {

                        isInOrOut = "in";

                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_1_TIME, dateStr);
                        values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_2_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
                        values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_3_INOUT, isInOrOut);
                        Activity_Landing.dbWritable.insert(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                    } else {

                        isInOrOut = "out";
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.i("CallLogDetailsActivity", "Getting Log activity...");
                                String[] projection = new String[]{CallLog.Calls.NUMBER};
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // TODO: Consider calling
                                    return;
                                }
                                Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " desc");
                                cur.moveToFirst();
                                lastCallnumber = cur.getString(0);

                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_1_TIME, dateStr);
                                values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_2_NUMBER, lastCallnumber);
                                values.put(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.COLUMN_3_INOUT, isInOrOut);
                                Activity_Landing.dbWritable.insert(CallRecorderSQLite.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                            }
                        }, 500);
                    }

                    Log.d("calling number idle", "" + incomingNumber);
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("Exception ------", "" + ex.toString());
        }
    }
};

public File createDirIfNotExists() {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PhoneCallRecording");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "folder is created");
        }
    }
    File file = new File(folder, dateStr + ".amr");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "file is created");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change manifest to this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<receiver android:name=".MyPhoneReceiver" > 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

and code:

```
... 
@Override public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {    

if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())) { 
    final String originalNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER); 

} 
...
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473508/not-getting-correct-value-when-retrieving-current-outgoing-phone-number-in-andro)